# Custom RecordReader in EMR Job

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

How do I specify a custom `RecordReader` to use in job flow on Amazon EMR?

**Note:** Hadoop newbie here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify input format in the your driver class (the class containtin "main" of the job. Record reader is logical part of Your input format which actually return it to the mapping task. 
I do not think it is something specific to the EMR.